# Using results of \d command in psql

Tags: postgresql, command-line-interface, psql

The command `\d` in `psql` lists all tables, views, and sequences. Is there a way to catch this output into a table and run a query on it?

```
mydb-> \d

      List of relations
Schema |  Name  | Type  |   Owner
-------+--------+-------+---------
public | mytab1 | table | username

mydb-> select * from <use relation from \d> where Type='view';

      List of relations
Schema |  Name  | Type  |   Owner
-------+--------+-------+---------
```

Alternatively, is there a way to use `select-from-where` query to get this table and other table meta data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the query behind `\d` if you start `psql` with the `-E` option. Then running `\d` will also show the metadata query.

Once you have that query, it should be easy to adapt it to your needs.

If you need it to builld a list of DDL statements, you can use `psql`'s `\gexec` to execute the results of a query as SQL statements.

Comment: without restarting, set `\set ECHO_HIDDEN on;` to show those queries.

Comment: Thanks for the response, will check it now

Comment: @Laurenz Albe - Thank you! Its great to know about the `-E` option. Solved a big hurdle of mine.

Comment: Note that it's actually `\set ECHO_HIDDEN on` without the semicolon, or else it gets sad. :*(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the query, you can run `\set ECHO_HIDDEN on` like in the comments above. If you do that, you'll get the query:

```sql
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  c.relname as "Name",
  CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'm' THEN 'materialized view' WHEN 'i' THEN 'index' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 's' THEN 'special' WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign table' WHEN 'p' THEN 'partitioned table' WHEN 'I' THEN 'partitioned index' END as "Type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) as "Owner"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','p','v','m','S','f','')
      AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
      AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

So, ya know, there ya go.